# What does Windows UWP do with my Lazy initialized Singleton classes when the app is suspended?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a UWP application that runs on Windows 10 Mobile, written in c#. I am having an issue with one of my classes that needs to be a Singleton and which I initialized using the Lazy pattern. Here is how I have done it (which is pretty much how everyone does it)

```
public class WindowsUniversalScanners
{
    private static readonly Lazy<WindowsUniversalScanners> lWindowsScanner = new Lazy<WindowsUniversalScanners>(() => new WindowsUniversalScanners());

    public static WindowsUniversalScanners Instance { get { return lWindowsScanner.Value; } }

    public delegate void ScannerDataEventHandler(ScannerDataEventArgs se);

    public event ScannerDataEventHandler onScanData;

    public delegate void ScannerStatusEventHandler(ScannerStatusEventArgs se);

    public event ScannerStatusEventHandler onScanStatus;

    public delegate void ScannerInitializationStatus(ScannerInitEventArgs si);

    public event ScannerInitializationStatus onScannerInit;

    private WindowsUniversalScanners()
    {
        StartScanner();
    }
```

Everything works fine when the app is started from scratch and used "normally". However, if the app is ever suspended (meaning you switch to another app, hit the windows key, etc...) and then resumed, the events in this class do not raise any longer.

I can also put breakpoints in the code inside of this class and see that breakpoints are hit as they should be before suspend but after suspend, breakpoints do not hit anymore (which is ultimately why the events never fire).

So, I am assuming that Windows destroyed my Singleton when the app was suspended? Note, this is not a time thing either. I read that when an app is suspended x seconds and the OS needs to free resources it can terminate things. However, this issue happens even if I suspend for only a second and come right back in. Most other functions of the app still work fine after resume.

So, can somebody confirm what the OS does to Singletons when the app is suspended specifically? I have done a ton of reading on the MSDN docs for app lifecycle but nothing addresses this particular issue.

Also, what is the best way to confirm that in fact this class is null? Can I check if Instance = null to verify? Assuming it is, I guess I just need to re-instantiate it?

Thanks!

Comment: This may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/suspend-an-app If no one answers your question, but you work out a solution, you should post the answer to your question here.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it wasn't the class that got disposed. I believe it could have gotten disposed by GC after a period of 5 to 10 seconds IF there are not references to the class any longer. This would satisfy the criteria for the OS to Dispose this class while suspended in an effort to reduce the footprint of a suspended app. However, this was not my case because it is a Singleton and I was still holding a reference to it from my page.

NOTE!!! In my case the hardware was a barcode scanner in the PointOfService namespace. However, it stands to reason that this issue could happen with any of the hardware items in Windows.Devices or other namespaces. Things like NFC, GPS, etc.. you should be wary of after resuming from a suspended state and check the below solution for your application:

So, one of the other things the OS will "cleanup" when suspended is any hardware resources. In my case, I had a barcode scanner using the namespace:

```
using Windows.Devices.PointOfService;
```

Which you then have to "Claim" the scanner by doing something like this:

```
BarcodeScanner.ClaimScannerAsync();
```

But, as I learned, at any point the OS can dispose the claim to your device. There is one other caveat to be aware of. If you do something like this inside of your class or Singleton like I did:

```
private BarcodeScanner scanner = null;
public ClaimedBarcodeScanner ClaimedScanner { get; set; } = null;
```

And then in your constructor or other initialization methods, you populate those properties with your BarcodeScanner and ClaimedBarcodeScanner objects and then the OS disposes the connection to the hardware and you lose the "claim" to them, your objects will not be null again but if you try to access or use them, you will get a ObjectDisposedException. This is key because when you try to reconnect at any point, particularly after a resume, you cannot just test to see if those properties are null because they won't be. Instead, you have to try to use them in a try/catch block and catch the ObjectDisposedException and at that point, reconnect or reclaim your hardware (or scanner in my case).

So, what I did is get the App Resuming event and then in that event, try to use the object and if I catch the exception, use that to reconnect like this:

```
private WindowsUniversalScanners()
{
    //Get our event for when the app resumes from suspended state
    Application.Current.Resuming += App_Resuming;
    StartScanner();
}

private async void App_Resuming(object sender, object e)
{
    try
    {
        //When the app resumes from suspended state, the ClaimedScanner object will be disposed but NOT null. This means the only 
        //way to trap this is try to access a property in the object and catch an ObjectDisposedException. 
        var scannerStatus = ClaimedScanner.IsEnabled;
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException oe)
    {
        //Now we know we are in a stuck state, we can try to heal from it. First we destroy scanner object and set it to null.
        if (DestroyScanner())
        {
            //Finally we re-start the scanner
            await StartScanner();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!